# R tidymodels xgboost Ubuntu 20.04 Error: C stack usage 7975188 is too close to the limit

Tags: r, ubuntu, xgboost, tidymodels

I am trying to run an `xgboost` model through `tidymodels` on an Ubuntu server but am getting the following error:
`Resample01: preprocessor 1/1: Error: C stack usage  7977188 is too close to the limit`

I've tried all the solutions suggested from googling C Stack usage errors (most of them say to remove unnecessary recursion and to set `ulimit -s unlimited`, but nothing has helped. I'm essentially following [this guide](https://juliasilge.com/blog/xgboost-tune-volleyball/) for tuning the model. My dataset is  about 2000 rows by 900 columns, and I'm just using a `group_vfold_cv()` cross validation with 10 groups, so nothing crazy. The server has 30gb of ram, 300gb ssd and 4 cores. The exact same code works on my windows 10 laptop with far less ram, so it must have something to do with the operating system.

All packages are up to date, and I've tried installing xgboost from source, nothing has helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems the error is actually due to the `recipe()` function using a recursive function `fun_calls()` with known errors [see here](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/issues/548). The solution is to use `update_role()` rather than a formula to specify the model.